# Shaco + Gargolyte Stoneplate

Tags: league-of-legends

If **Shaco** activates **Gargolyte Stoneplate's active**, will it decrease clone damage?

- Part 1: Shacos clone **autoattack** damage?
- Part 2: Shacos clone **explosion** damage?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shaco's clone counts as a **[summoned unit](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Champion_summoned_units)** and those behave pretty weird sometimes. In this specific scenario the clone behaves as a separate unit with separate stats and most importantly, **buffs and debuffs**.

I just tried it in the practice tool and the auto attacks of the clone are **not affected** by the damage reduction of the Item active. This means your clone will deal more damage than you, for as long as Gargoyle's is active.

Now the explosion of the clone is a different story since it's considered to be an **ability**. Since the ability will gain damage based on Shaco's current buffs and ability power this means that the explosion of the clone **will deal less damage** if your Stoneplate is active.

One thing to note: If you activate your clone while Gargoyle's is active, your clone will get your current bonus health but not the damage penalty.

Comment: This seems like a bug... *"One thing to note: If you activate your clone while Gargoyle's is active, your clone will get your current bonus health but not the damage penalty."*

Comment: @clcto I don't really think it's a bug. It's a **"Clone"**. It copies your stats (well only 75% of your AD). Gargoyle's gives you actual bonus health while not lowering your AD. The damage reduction comes from a debuff and as I mentioned in the answer, the clone has it's own buffs/debuffs.